How to fully recreate a Testcontainers container before each test?
I'm looking for a solution to have a new container for each test. My issue is that the data that I insert in the database in my first test will interferer the second test. Every test works independently but not when I run the complet test class.
I have manyToOne relations, and even with the setup() method I added, I have somme errors like "this entity with id 1L does not exists", but I juste saved it one line before in the same test. Also, when I set id = 1L to an entity, in the debug mud I see that the id set is not really 1L, it can be 9L.
This is my code, that uses the same container for each test :
@ActiveProfiles("postgres")
@Testcontainers
@DataJpaTest
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = JpaConfiguration.class, basePackages = "foo.bar.repository")
@EntityScan("foo.bar.entity")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class DockConflictViewContainerTest {

@Container
public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:14-alpine");

@Autowired
FooBarRepository fooBarRepository;

//Other repositories...

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void configureProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgres::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgres::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgres::getPassword);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("truncate table fooBar cascade").executeUpdate();
        // other truncates
    }

    @Transactional
    public void refreshMaterializedView() {
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW foo_bar_view").executeUpdate();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void testMaterializedView_shouldFindOneLine() {
        FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
        fooBar.setId(1L)
        fooBarRepository.save(fooBar);

        refreshMaterializedView();

        List<FooBarView> fooBarViews = fooBarViewRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(fooBarViews).hasSize(1);
    }
}

This is my properties file in yaml :
spring:
  application.name: truck
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/changelog.xml
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create
        generate_statistics: true
        show_sql: true

I tried to empty the database manually with truncate.
I tried to restart the container but it didn't work because my test are not working when I remove the @Container annotation.
I tried to re run the liquibase changelog.xml that is ran before the tests, but it didn't found all the files mentioned in the changelog.xml.
I think the most simple way is to recreate the container but I don't find how to do that.

I updated your tags, as you are obviously using the JUnit5 extension to testcontainers.

From official documentation:

Containers declared as static fields will be shared between test methods. They will be started only once before any test method is executed and stopped after the last test method has executed. Containers declared as instance fields will be started and stopped for every test method.

Remove the static from your @Container declaration.

You're right. The issue is that I can't use @DynamicPropertySource with a non static "postgres" variable.
I tried to create a non static variable but I'm facing issues with liquibase authentification. It's like it's not possible to set the credentials of the container in a @BeforeEach

I think I found a way to do that https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/a4d943072e38ce7d347e66476ccbf6412fb31545/testing-modules/spring-testing-2/src/test/java/com/baeldung/dynamicproperties/PostgreSQLExtension.java#L8
